# Reason for using jQuery over javascript besides less code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-mobile

I started using Javascript for HTML5 mobile development but noticed I can use the jQuery library as well. My question is, does jQuery do anything besides require you to write less code? Is Javascript faster in performance? Sorry for the newbie question but I couldn't find an answer and really interested in the difference. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery is a library built in JavaScript. The more you abstract the less performance you'll get. For example, just selecting an element with the native DOM methods is going to be way faster than doing the same with jQuery.

So the question is not quite "find out which one is faster", you already know jQuery is going to be slower. The question is more like "is the performance hit worth it?". And yes, most of the time it is because the time you save in writing code is much more valuable than the performance hit you get, which most of time is simply negligible.

Another factor is the quality of your vanilla JavaScript code. jQuery has been tested and maintained for years, and it shows.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly the answer I was looking for. Sorry for the newbie question again

Answer (score 0):

Your question should not be "should I use jQuery or plain JavaScript" but rather "which library should I use?". No one should be starting a substantial project with zero code, they should have at least a good collection of robust, tested code that can easily be collated into a library or tool kit.

The problem with a general library is that it must provide general solutions, hence why jQuery has 4,000 lines of code that any one project might only really need a few hundred lines of. Some libraries have very many more lines of code. If you use someone else's library, you are often bound to their update schedule and may well end up using plugins that require different versions of the library.

If you have your own library, or one developed and maintained in your work area, you get the same reuse of code and can cut your cloth to suit the project. jQuery (and most general libraries) are monolithic: it's all or nothing, you can't include just one part or another (e.g. you might just want a good *addListener* function). Your own library can be modular, so you only include the code you need and can avoid many of the cross–browser issues that general libraries must deal with.  David Mark's "MyLibrary" is one of the very few modular libraries.

Also, cross–browser differences are becoming less and less of an issue and the DOM API is becoming richer so there is less and less need to use a general library. E.g. no one accounts for *document.all* anymore, or bothers with browsers that don't support either *addEventListener* or *attachEvent*. Once support for IE 6 and 7 can be dropped (a few years yet) there will be very little reason to use a monolithic third party library, modularity will be the key. Everything will be a plugin, there will be no need for a base library, or the base library will be very small to provide a generic API for basic DOM functions.

Comment: While "no one should be starting a substantial project with zero code" holds a certain value, there is **much less** value in people *learning* jQuery, and knowing nothing of JavaScript. This basically leads to programmers not knowing how the internals of JavaScript work, and thus posting questions such as *"OMG! Why doesn't `$('#myDiv') == $('#myDiv')`????"*. There's **always** value in starting from zero at some point; especially since the OP is just starting.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to write all that. I really like your idea of creating ones own library for their specific need in whatever project they are currently working on. It makes a lot of sense and will definitely be heeding your advice. Thanks once again for taking the time to write all that

Comment: Incidentally, the concept that "less code is better" is flawed. "Less code" is not a good reason, on it's own, to do anything. It should be the least of your concerns, particularly where a minimiser will be used. "Less code" is often harder to debug and maintain, as is the chaining of function calls common to many libraries. A very long time ago estimates of software development effort focused on functionality, not lines of code, a focus that hasn't changed, particularly as cutting code is probably less than 20% of the overall cost of a software development project.